# IPSec Sniff Traffic

Tags: man-in-the-middle, ipsec, sniffing

I'm wondering if it is possible to Sniff IPSec connections.

At the beginning of a connection, the two peers agree on a SA and exchange a PSK or Certificates.

What I'm thinking about, is to intercept the SA-agreement. On the client-side, the attacker could act like the server, on the server-side the attacker could work like the client.

```
|Client|<---IPSec--->|Attacker|<---IPSec--->|Server|
```

Comment: Thank you. I removed the parts with ssl-strip and described my idea in another way

Comment: That's the point of PKI. You know which certificate to expect, and someone impersonating by presenting a certificate for which they do not posses private keys will fail during the negotiation.